# Creating a select COUNT with many SUBSTR

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a code in SQL what must return the number of occourrencies of some substrings.

I need to count the number of times that the substrs repeat.

```
Ex:
Substring 'LQX' -> 10 times
Substring 'TES' -> 5 times

(select count(cod_ordem_producao) 
 from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao
 where substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3)='LQR') LQR,
(select count(cod_ordem_producao)
 from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao
 where substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3)='TES') TES
from Dual
```

How can I put a date filter in this code? (between dates)

Thx

Comment: You need *conditional aggregation* using CASE. Or if it's always the first three charecters: `select substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3), count(cod_ordem_producao) 
 from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao grouo by 
 substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3) `

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when cod_ordem_producao like 'LQR%' then 1 else 0 end) as lqr,
       sum(case when cod_ordem_producao like 'TES%' then 1 else 0 end) as tes
from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao
where <whatever additional conditions you want>;
```

If you more generally want to know what the first three characters are of the string, you can use `group by`:

```
select substr(cod_ordem_producao, 1, 3) as first_three,
       count(*)
from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao
where <whatever additional conditions you want>
group by substr(cod_ordem_producao, 1, 3);
```

This puts the values in separate *rows* rather than in separate *columns*.

Answer (score 0):

Group based on the substring and then filter out for dates

```
select substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3) as substr_val
       ,count(cod_ordem_producao) 
  from qt_qts.pla_ordem_producao
 where substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3) in ('LQR','TEST')
   and <date filter criteria>
group by substr(cod_ordem_producao,1,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!